# How to enable a WebPartDisplayMode

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

I am trying to add a webpart to page and I cannot get the "Edit" mode to enable.  Only the browse mode is enabled.  How do I enable Edit and Design modes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might enable `<Personalization Enabled="true" />` in webpartmanager. And set the webparts's `AllowEdit` property to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue and then realized that I need to login/authenticate with a user before I can see the design/edit mode. That's because whatever changes you do it will be saved & associated to your logged user.